# Printing PDF with Windows Service while no user is logged on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2

Our customer wants to have a Windows Service running, which is generating a PDF, save it to a folder and print this PDF. This is working good so far.

The only problem that occured recently is that the IT admin told us, that there will be no user logged on to the Windows Server 2008, while the service is running. But when printing the PDF, we need to open a PDF Reader, which will start the printing process. This will not work - as far as I understood from the research I did - because no desktop was initialized, which is necessary when printing this way.

So my question is, how can a PDF be printed through code

- without sending raw data to a printer
- without spending loads of money on third party software
- without a user logged on to the system

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Printing from a Windows Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/06/24/printing-from-a-windows-service/)

Comment: Oh wow, this is at least something new to me. I've just ran the sample code and it was working. But I have absolutely no clue, how to adapt the code to print an entire pdf file with it. Could you guide me also in the right direction at this point? It could be an option, but could also be to much effort to implement it this way.